# Difference with the pip installs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently using python3 for my windows, however while installing the modules, why does using

```
pip install module
or 
pip3 install module
```

doesnt work at all, the only one that successfully works and actually allows me to import the modules is only the line:

```
python3 -m pip install module
```

I've managed to successfully install the modules already but im just wondering what are the differences between the 3 lines of code and why one works instead of the other as ive seen guides online all use pip install module directly and it works just fine

Comment: Because `pip` and `pip3` aren't linked to the same Python installation that `python3` is, for some reason or another. Perhaps because you have multiple versions installed and/or installed them via different means.